# Unable to parse SASS on CSS - Liferay

Tags: css, sass, liferay, weblogic

I'm running Liferay 6.1.1 on my WebLogic server and things seem to work fine except for this error I keep getting:

```
Unable to parse SASS on CSS C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\liferay\autodeploy\My-Theme\css\main.css
```

And then get an `org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException:`

Weird things to note are that this bulb icon repeats over in over in my Web Content, also it will not allow me to create my own web content (because permissions, which doesn't make sense. I'm the admin)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Does that CSS file validate?

Comment: Validate? What do you mean?

Comment: Is it a valid CSS document: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use that machine with my local files, but the main.CSS file is literally about 9 import statements of other files, and they're all fine

Comment: It allows for direct input.  If your CSS files are being sent through Sass, then it will choke on invalid CSS documents.  Invalid characters can cause problems, too (eg. characters that look like spaces, but aren't).  Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254361/error-compiling-css-asset-heroku-sass

Answer (score 4):

This was reported as a liferay bug and a patch was made available.

Basically the weblogic class loader couldn't handle the ruby gems correctly.

Check out the bug here: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-28665